# I never change my stripes

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I go to great lengths for you to understand
>
> I never change my stripes, I stick to what you planned
>
> I bend and reach for you, in any given frame
>
> With no delay, on your command, I'm back from whence I came

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's a:

> **Tape measure**
>  [image]

`I go to great lengths for you to understand`:

> It expand to great lengths so you can know/measure the distance between two points, or the length of something.

`I never change my stripes, I stick to what you planned`:

> Well, the stripes are the little lines on the tape that tell the measure (millimetters, centimetters, inchs, ...), it will be disasterous if they would change I think.

`I bend and reach for you, in any given frame`:

> Since it's a flexible tape, it can bend. And it can reach places you can't fit in them (like holes for example).

`With no delay, on your command, I'm back from whence I came`:

> When you finish mesauring something, you release your hand and it get back to its case (where it came from in the first place). Who didn't play with one of those when he was young?

Comment: Now that I have posted the answer, I'm not so sure about it.

Comment: Although I agree with this, I think the reasons for each sentence could be said in a better way.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi I wasn't going to add them anyway, but the post button didn't work (because I had to type at least ?? letters so I added them. I'll enhance them.

Comment: Correct. You were quick :)

Comment: @rybo111 thanks! I played with it all the time when I was a kid. It was spontaneous.

Answer (score -1):

It could be

> Map with zoom in/zoom out features

As,

> A digital map can be adjusted as per one's convenience (It could be an astro-atlas to understand great lengths)

Never changed my stripes, I stick to what is planned

> Could refer to almost fixed/static night sky plotted on an atlas with different zones of light/regions with varying intensities of light

I bend and reach for you in any given frame - could mean

> digital atlas can be accessed in any smart device

With no delay, at a command, I am back- refers to

> The minimze/maximize/restore options available as controls in a digitalized map.